# Weighted Average in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Please consider this tables:

Weight:

```
City          Weight
--------------------
Tokyo          100
München        150
Köln           200
```

and  Data:

```
ID       Country       City           Value
--------------------------------------------
1        Germany       München        10
2        Germany       München        20
3        Japan         Tokyo          12
4        Japan         Tokyo          20
5        Japan         Tokyo          8
6        Germany       Köln           5 
7        Germany       Köln           7
8        Germany       Köln           9
```

I want to calculate Weighted Average for each Country:

I wrote this query:

```
var MyResult = (from d in MyContext.Data
                join w in MyContext.Weight
                on d.City equals w.City
                select new {
                   d.Country,
                   d.City,
                   d.Value,
                   w.Weight
                }).GroupBy(p=>new {p.Country})
                  .Select(o=>new
                             {
                                 o.Key.Country,
                                 WeightedAverage = o.Sum(k=>k.Value * k.Weight) / o.Sum(k=>k.Weight)
                             })
```

But it returns wrong Weighted Average for me. I want to calculate this formula:

For Germany:

```
(10 * 150 + 20 * 150 + 5 * 200 + 7 * 200 + 9 * 200) / (150 + 150 + 200 + 200 + 200)
```

How can I achieve my desire result ?

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated and nitpicky: It's "Köln" :D

Comment: How would you write the *SQL* query? A simple JOIN like the one you tried here would repeat the city weight in every row. You'd have to calculate the *actual* city weight before the JOIN, either with a CTE or subquery. The *Weight* table should include the Country. You can calculate the country weight with eg `SELECT City, Weight/SUM(Weight) OVER( PARTITION BY Country) FROM Weights`. The clause `SUM(Weight) OVER( PARTITION BY Country)` calculates the sum for all rows in the partition and repeats it in every row.

Comment: You need distinct values of the weights, I am not sure EF can translate this into SQL but you need something like this: `WeightedAverage = o.Sum(k=>k.Value * k.Weight) / o.DistinctBy(k=> k.City).Sum(k=>k.Weight)`

Comment: @Eldar `DistinctBy` is not translatable AFAIK - see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27470.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I usually solve problem in first step and then optimize it. For this problem I haven't `Partition` operator in EF.

Comment: @Eldar: **I am not sure EF can translate this into SQL** : this is the problem

Comment: @Fildor: I updated my question. Thanks German man

Comment: @GuruStron Sadly it has an open issue on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27470)

Comment: @DooDoo EF is an ORM, not embedded SQL. This isn't an optimization issue, it's using the wrong tool for the job. The formula you posted requires calculating the weight in a very particular way in advance. You can't do that *after* the JOIN.

Comment: you can't use distinct anyway for these kind of queries, because it might remove valid values

Comment: @Eldar yes, I have linked it )

Comment: I wish @JonSkeet would see this post.

Comment: @Eldar distinct values will only work by random chance. What if two cities have the same weight? BTW this is called a non-additive measure in data warehouses

Comment: You can write one join query to sum the weights and another to perform weighted sum  and then join them. Either via EF if it supports this or in-memory.

Comment: @DooDoo Jon Skeet would tell you the same thing. This isn't a C# question, it's a SQL question. Wrong query, wrong results. Your formula requires calculating the city weight first. You can do that in a subquery or view. If you use a view you'll be able to map it to eg a `CityView` entity that can be joined with the data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You are right. Could you please write `SQL` version of query? Thanks

Comment: @DooDoo I have described one approach to the SQL version of the query.

Comment: @GuruStron: Could you please write your `SQL` version as an answer? Thanks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Could you please the `SQL` version of your query with `Partition` as  an answer? Thanks

Comment: @DooDoo I see you have changed the formula, now you have duplication. Can you please elaborate what is wrong with answer EF gives you? Also can you please add the EF generated query and entities definitions?

Comment: @GuruStron: Sorry I thought I wrote all weight in denominator. The problem is Weight is not take part in formula based on every city.

Comment: @DooDoo please add the actual results produced by EF Query based on the sample data. And the generated SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you please write SQL version of query?

Since you have very your data denormalized in very peculiar way one way to handle it would be by creating a subquery which will create the `Country` -> `SUM(Weight)` "mapping". For example (since SQL Sever does not seem to have `first` aggregate function I substitute it here with `max` which will not work correctly in cases when some data is missing in `Weight` table):

```sql
WITH WeightDict(Country, Weight) as (
  select Country, sum(Weight) as Weight
  from (
   select Country, w.City, max(Weight) as Weight
   from Weight w
   join Data d on w.City = d.City
   group by Country, w.City) sub
  group by Country
)

select d.Country, 1.0 * sum(d.Value * w.Weight)/max(wd.Weight) as WeightedAverage 
from Data d
join Weight w on w.City = d.City
join WeightDict wd on d.Country = wd.Country
group by d.Country
```

Sample db fiddle - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fg1rXi5gTPjcGv7MS35TGB/1 . Output:

| country | weightedaverage |
| --- | --- |
| Germany | 24.8571428571428571 |
| Japan | 40.0000000000000000 |

Not sure that this is possible to rewrite in form of EF Core LINQ query but you can try to do it in parts (i.e. one for fetching dictionary and another to fetch weighted sum - `sum(d.Value * w.Weight)`) and perform final join in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure EF can translate this too but it will be too long to write in a comment so I will post it as an answer. Try this :

```
var MyResult = (from d in MyContext.Data
                join w in MyContext.Weight
                on d.City equals w.City
                select new {
                   d.Country,
                   d.City,
                   d.Value,
                   w.Weight
                }).GroupBy(p=>new {p.Country})
                  .Select(o=>new
                             {
                                 o.Key.Country,
                                 WeightedAverage = o.Sum(k=>k.Value * k.Weight) / 
       MyContext.Weight.Where(w=> o.Select(q=> q.City).Contains(w.City))
                       .Select(w=> w.Weight))).Sum()
                             })

 // or another alternate:
 WeightedAverage = o.Sum(k=>k.Value * k.Weight) /
 o.GroupBy(r=> r.City).Select(r=> r.First())Sum(k=>k.Weight)
```

**Edit:**

If the above query doesn't work, only two options left: Enumerate the query so you can use in-memory LINQ where you can utilize `DistinctBy` or write a raw SQL using a library like `Dapper`

Here is the equivalent SQL for SQL Server :

```
SELECT Sum(w.weight * d.value) / Sum(q.weight) WeightedAverage,
       d.country
FROM   weights w
       INNER JOIN data d
               ON w.city = d.city
       CROSS apply (SELECT weight
                    FROM   weights z
                    WHERE  z.city IN (SELECT x.city
                                      FROM   data x
                                      WHERE  x.country = d.country)) q
GROUP  BY d.country
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TwDhBq2e)

And BTW having a `Country` column in the Weight table would make writing queries easier.

Comment: EF supports execution of raw SQL.

Comment: @jmcilhinney AFAIK EF supports Raw SQL for these result types: Entity, Scalar, and NonQuery so for a non-entity custom result type you need to map a `View`